# Angular Router - Cannot match any routes when redirecting to an URL with query parameters

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular4-router

I'm experiencing some problems with angular router in an angular 4 application while using `returnUrl` together with a query string.

So I have my routes specified like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  canActivate: [AccessibilityGuard],
  canActivateChild: [AccessibilityGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'info',
      component: InfoComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'xpto/graphic',
          component: XptoGraphicComponent,
        },
      ]
    },
    ...
  ];
}];
```

And inside my `AccessibilityGuard` I have the following:

```
...
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  const token = CookieHelper.getCookie('accessToken');
  if(token == null || token == '') {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
```

So, considering that I try to navigate to a specific page of my `XptoGraphicComponent`, my URL can be something like: `http://localhost:4200/info/xpto/graphic?a=1&b=2&c=3`.
If my `AccessibilityGuard` doesn't find the accessToken, it will redirect me to the login page. After that, my url will be: `http://localhost:4200/login?returnUrl=/info/xpto/graphic?a=1&b=2&c=3`.

After the login, the redirect doesn't work and I get the following error on my browser console:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'info/xpto/graphic?a=1&b=2&c=3'
```

This problem only occurs when I have query parameters in my url along with the `returnURL`.
Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that your `/info...` url is nested as a child of the `home` path?

Comment: Oh sorry, actually the path to the HomeComponent is an empty string ' ' and not 'home'. I've corrected it, sorry

Comment: What code are you using to perform the redirect? I have used Router.navigateByUrl() in the past... https://angular.io/api/router/Router#usage-2

Comment: I'm using the `navigate()`, but even with the `navigateByUrl` it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Can you provide the code that navigates to returnUrl?

Comment: You were right after all @96ethanh , the `navigateByUrl()` solved it! I was referring to the  `navigate()` from the `AccessibilityGuard` and not the one taking care of the `returnUrl`. Thanks :)